# MSVC UTF8 string encoding uses incorrect code points

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, unicode

I'm trying to write the character "Ā" (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0100/index.htm) into a C++11 UTF8 string (using `u8` prefix).

```
const char *const utf8 = u8"Ā";
const char *const utf8_2 = u8"\u0100";
const char *const chars = "Ā";

const int utf8_len = strlen(utf8);
const int utf8_2_len = strlen(utf8_2);
const int chars_len = strlen(chars);
```

Running this under MSVC (16.2.4) results in:

```
utf8_len == 5
utf8_2_len = 2;
chars_len = 2;
```

Where:

```
utf8 == "Ã„â‚¬"
utf8_2 == "Ä€"
chars == "Ä€"
```

The source file is set to UTF8 (without BOM).

Trying the same with Clang and GCC works as expected:

https://godbolt.org/z/PNZFCa

Does anyone know why this behaviour is occurring? Why is the `u8` prefixed Unicode character being encoded as 5 bytes (when it should be 2)?

Comment: Could be a compiler bug. Have you considered reporting it?

Comment: My guess is, it gets double-encoded. First the text editor encodes `Ā` as two bytes `"Ä€"`, and then the compiler takes it as two-character Latin-1 string and further encodes each character as UTF-8. Try saving your .cpp file as "UTF-8 with signature", so the compiler knows to read the source as UTF-8 and not Latin-1.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik saving with UTF8 BOM does work around the issue. In this case, I think this is a compiler bug, so I'll get it reported.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/795433/c11-utf-8-strings-get-encoded-twice-in-files-with.html

Comment: It's not a bug.  Most Windows programs assume files are ANSI encoded for backward compatibility with legacy Windows usage, and UTF-8 w/ BOM is needed for differentiation.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've replied to your answer below, but, the file was saved as UTF-8 without BOM (mentioned in my question, `The source file is set to UTF8 (without BOM).`).

Comment: Yes, as I said, if you save without BOM, the compiler assumes ANSI encoding and not UTF-8. It needs to be told with a command line switch. If the BOM is present you won’t need the switch.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, when I add a Unicode character to a new source file, and attempt to save, it warns `Some Unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current codepage. Do you want to resave this file as Unicode in order to maintain your data?`. The current codepage is 1252. Choosing `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)` first prevents any warnings during save. I agree adding `/utf-8` fixes the issue, but VS suggests UTF-8 without BOM is a legitimate choice.

Comment: It's a legitimate choice, but it is still a text file in *some* encoding, with no indication what the encoding is.  It's "just a bunch of bytes".  Most Windows programs, including the MSVC compiler, assume the encoding of a file is the localized ANSI encoding unless there is a BOM.   A file that starts with bytes EF BB BF (The U+FEFF Unicode BOM character encoded in UTF-8) is a UTF-8 file.  If it starts with `FF FE` it is a UTF-16LE-encoded file, etc.  Without a BOM, the compiler assumes ANSI.  That's why `/source-charset:` switch exists.

Comment: Also note that many *Linux* programs do not like a BOM at the start of the file, so the option exists to save without it if you have portable source, but you still need to tell the Microsoft compiler what the encoding is, if not its default assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft compiler assumes the local ANSI encoding for files without BOM, which is probably Windows-1252 in your case.  If you run `cl /?` from the command line, you'll see the following command line switches:

```
...
/source-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn set source character set
/execution-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn set execution character set
/utf-8 set source and execution character set to UTF-8
...
```

Use `/source-charset:UTF-8` or `/utf-8` if you don't want to save with BOM.

#### Test code saved in UTF-8 without BOM:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *const utf8 = u8"Ā";
    printf("%zu\n",strlen(utf8));
}
```

#### Output:

```
C:\>cl /nologo test.cpp
test.cpp

C:\>test
5

C:\>cl /nologo /utf-8 test.cpp
test.cpp

C:\>test
2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I used Save As (with encoding) and chose UTF-8 (without BOM). So I'm still convinced it is a bug.

Comment: @MarkIngram The BOM is the metadata telling Windows programs a file is encoded in UTF-8.  Without it, it could be saved in Windows-1252 or Windows-1251 or UTF-8 or any other encoding.  The compiler assumes ANSI encoding (the localized encoding of the version of Windows...US Windows == Windows-1252 for example) unless otherwise told.